# Segmentation Fault while running following C program

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, undefined-behavior, string-literals

This C program takes planet names as arguments and prints if they are planet or not. The good case is working

> `./planets Venus Mercury`

But if I add bad case I am getting `Segmentation Fault`.

> `./planets Venus Mercury mercury`

What can be the reason for this? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_PLANETS 9

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char *planets[] = { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Pluto" };
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_PLANETS; j++) {
            if (strcmp(argv[i], planets[j]) == 0) {
                printf("%s is planet %d\n", argv[i], j + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j == NUM_PLANETS) {
            printf("%s is not a planet\n", argv[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `NUM_PLANETS` is 9, but you only have 8 planets in your array.

Comment: Your array is initialized with 8 strings but `NUM_PLANETS` is 9, so you are accessing one element after the end of the array. I suggest to replace `NUM_PLANETS` with `(sizeof(planets) / sizeof(planets[0]))`.

Comment: The C tradition is to use a `NULL` terminated array of automatic size rather than *assuming* it's a particular size.

Comment: the number of planets should be 8, and the last one should be Neptune, not Pluto.

Comment: Also... better testing would have helped. `./planets testname` would have crashed in the same way

Comment: @raphire "Neptune" is sad, being left output the party.  Review `char *planets[] = { ... }`.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks for answer. I have accepted the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You declared an array of `8` elements

```
char *planets[] = { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Pluto" };
```

but in the condition of the inner for loop

```
for (j = 0; j < NUM_PLANETS; j++) {
```

you are using the macro `NUM_PLANETS` that is set to `9`

```
#define NUM_PLANETS 9
```

As a result within the for loop there can be an access to memory outside the array that results in undefined behavior.

Using the macro makes your program error-prone.

Instead you could within `main` to determine the real number of elements in the array the following way

```
char *planets[] = { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Pluto" };
const size_t NUM_PLANETS = sizeof( planets ) / sizeof( *planets );
```

In this case even if the array will be enlarged supplying new string literals used as initializers your program will be correct and you will need to change nothing.

The second remark is that using the statement `break` within the inner for loop makes your program less readable. It is just a bad style of programming.

And you should declare variables in minimum scopes where they are used.

Instead you could write the program for example the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    const char *planets[] = 
    { 
        "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Pluto" 
    };
    const size_t NUM_PLANETS = sizeof( planets ) / sizeof( *planets );

    for ( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ ) 
    {
        size_t j = 0;

        while ( j < NUM_PLANETS && strcmp( argv[i], planets[j] ) != 0 ) ++j;

        if ( j != NUM_PLANETS ) 
        {
            printf( "%s is planet %zu\n", argv[i], j + 1 );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "%s is not a planet\n", argv[i] );
        }
    }
}
```

Pay attention to the qualifier `const` within the type specifiers in the array declaration. Though in C string literals have types of non-constant character arrays (by historical reasons) nevertheless any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior. So it is better to define such arrays as in the program with the qualifier `const`. Moreover in C++ string literals have types of constant character arrays. So you wll be even able to compile your program using a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 9):

The code has undefined behavior because the initializer for the array `planets` has only 8 entries instead of 9, which is the value of `NUM_PLANETS`.
When the command line string argument is not found among the 8 entries, you compare it to `planets[8]`, which is an access beyond the end of the array and most probably an invalid pointer, causing the segmentation fault when is it dereferenced by `strcmp`.

You should add the missing entry `"Neptune"` in the initializer and you should compute the number of entries from the size of the array.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char *planets[] = {
        "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter",
        "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"
    };
    int num_planets = sizeof(planets) / sizeof(*planets);
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < num_planets; j++) {
            if (strcmp(argv[i], planets[j]) == 0) {
                printf("%s is planet %d\n", argv[i], j + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j == num_planets) {
            printf("%s is not a planet\n", argv[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you could add a null pointer terminator in `planets`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char *planets[] = {
        "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter",
        "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto", NULL
    };

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        for (int j = 0;; j++) {
            if (!planets[j]) {
                printf("%s is not a planet\n", argv[i]);
                break;
            }
            if (strcmp(argv[i], planets[j]) == 0) {
                printf("%s is planet %d\n", argv[i], j + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Whether [Pluto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto) should or should not be present in the array is [debatable](https://www.loc.gov/everyday-mysteries/item/why-is-pluto-no-longer-a-planet/). If you include [Dwarf planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarf_planet), other candidates should be present too:  Eris, Haumea, Makemake, Gonggong, Quaoar, Sedna, Ceres, Orcus and Salacia...

Answer (score 5):

You access the array outside its bounds. It invokes undefined behaviour.

I would use a sentinel value or calculate the array size.

1.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* planets[] = { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Pluto", NULL};
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        for (j = 0; planets[j]; j++) {
            if (strcmp(argv[i], planets[j]) == 0) {
                printf("%s is planet %d\n", argv[i], j + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!planets[j]) {
            printf("%s is not a planet\n", argv[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nMfdd5nf3

2.

```
#define NUM_PLANETS(list) (sizeof(list) / sizeof((list)[0]))

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* planets[] = { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Pluto"};
    int i;
    size_t j;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_PLANETS(planets); j++) {
            if (strcmp(argv[i], planets[j]) == 0) {
                printf("%s is planet %zu\n", argv[i], j + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j == NUM_PLANETS(planets)) {
            printf("%s is not a planet\n", argv[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/71er14q3f

Comment: Any particular reason to use `sizeof((list)[1])` instead of `sizeof((list)[0])`?

Comment: @chqrlie No - it does not matter as there is no dereference

Comment: Of course it does not matter, so one could write `sizeof((list)[9])` or `sizeof((list)[42])` for fun or `sizeof 0[list]` to save 3 characters, or even without any hard coded numbers: `#define ARRAY_LENGTH(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a)[sizeof(a)])`

Comment: @chqrlie indeed

Answer (score 2):

You have initialized the array for 8 planets but in the second for loop you are accessing 9 elements. This gives segmentation fault as you are trying to access data which you haven't allocated to the array containing planets